# How to use Environment Variables from .env in NPM Scripts?

Tags: javascript, npm, environment-variables, package.json

I'm trying to run an npm package ([Apollo Rover](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/rover/)) via an npm script. The command on the package itself requires an Access Token, and I'm not comfortable having that directly in the package.json so wanted to pull it out and contain it in a .env that won't be commited.

I've tried using [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) and cross-env-shell, but my tests aren't working.

.env

```
ACCESS_TOKEN="jdaksc8ds7vp98vwy8"
```

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env-shell \"echo Hello $ACCESS_TOKEN\""
  }
}
```

Output

```
% npm run test

> test@0.0.1 test
> cross-env-shell "echo Hello $ACCESS_TOKEN"

Hello
```

Is there something I'm missing to provide this functionality? I also need this to run on *nix based systems and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) is used to set environment variables **inline** when running node commands. In your case you have defined your variables in a `.env` file which is different.

When populating environment variables from `.env` files you'll need to use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) or similar.

In your specific case I can recommend using [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) with the `-f` option as the simpler option.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "env-cmd -f ./custom/path/.env \"echo Hello $ACCESS_TOKEN\""
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tried `"env-cmd -f ./.env node \"echo Hello $ACCESS_TOKEN\""` and got the following error % npm run test

> test@0.0.1 test
> env-cmd -f ./.env node "echo Hello $ACCESS_TOKEN"

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './echo Hello '
    ... {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Comment: @ChazUK I have updated the script  command - removed the node as it is redundant in this case of just testing echo of a variable.

Comment: The output I'm still getting is `> env-cmd -f ./.env "echo Hello $ACCESS_TOKEN"`
`spawn echo Hello  ENOENT` and `env-cmd -f ./.env echo Hello $ACCESS_TOKEN` (removing the quotes returns `Hello `

Comment: Can you share the contents of your `.env`, more specifically the way the ACCESS_TOKEN has been defined?

Comment: Yep it's in the question. I have tried it both with and without quotes around the variable contents.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is still looking, here's a way to run a script via npm and read the .env variables.

// .env

```
MY_ENV_VAR: '46a69247498a030'
```

// package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "myscript1": "node myscript-cmd --cmd_name=script1",
  "myscript2": "node myscript-cmd --cmd_name=script2"
}
```

// myscript-cmd.js (placed at the save level of your package.json)

```
// accessing the value of 'cmd_var' passed as a command-line argument
const args = process.argv.slice(2); 
const argMap = args.reduce((acc, arg) => {
  const [key, value] = arg.split("=");
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});
const cmdVarValue = argMap["--cmd_name"];

if (cmdVarValue === "myscript1") {
  require("dotenv").config();
  const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;

  execSync(`echo hello: ${process.env.MY_ENV_VAR}`, {
    stdio: [0, 1, 2],
  });

} else if(cmdVarValue === "myscript2"){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to evaluate the `.env` properly

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env-shell \"echo Hello $(grep '^NODE_ENV' .env)\""
  }
}
```